# Добавление изображения в коде base64 в PDF при помощи ReportLab

Tags: python, django, pdf, base64

Стоит задача добавить в PDF изображения которые хранятся в базе в формате base64. Добавлять планирую сначала все в контейнер а потом строить документ.

```
from reportlab.platypus import Image
...
elements = []
...
elements.append(Image('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAZA...'))
```

Знаю что Image ожидает на входе получить путь к файлу, но что делать если у меня строка в base64? В общем не могу подружить класс Image со строкой base64.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо [пользователю django.ru Mr.Floppy](http://djbook.ru/auth/3111/) за ответ.

```
import base64
import io

from reportlab.platypus import Image

encoded_data = """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"""

data = base64.b64decode(encoded_data)
memory_file = io.BytesIO(data)
img = Image(memory_file)

print(img)
print(img.imageHeight)
print(img.imageWidth)
```